# 3d objects in c# - all the bodies belonging to the group are displayed on the positions shifted for the position of the group

Tags: c#, forms, object, 3d

abstract class GeometryBody{

```
int id; Point position;
    public GeometryBody(Point position)
    {
        this.position = position;
    }
}
```

Point is my class I use for creating points with different positions in Cartesian 3d coordinate system.

```
class Square : GeometryBody{
double a;
}

class Sphere : GeometryBody{
double r;
}

class Point{
double x; double y; double z;
    public Point(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}

class GroupOfBodies : GeometryBody{}
```

Now, what I need to do is make sure that plains of bodies are parallel to their respective axis. GroupOfBodies is a group of more 3d objects and needs to act like any 3d object would (it has its own position etc). I guess this was the easy part. Now what bugs me is how would I implement that all the bodies belonging to the group are displayed in the space on the positions shifted for the position of the group?

Comment: For what I understand `GroupOfBodies` will be a collection of `GeometryBody` and when you render the group it will internally render all the contained bodies, right? If that's the case then we need to know at least how a body is rendered to suggest something, but the simplest I can think is to create operators for Point and then when you render each body from the group sum the body position plus the group position.

Comment: I think you are on the right track here Now, I made inside GroupOfBodies a list which is called ListOfBodies. What I did is i made a method in GroupOfBodies like this:
        public void MoveBodiesPosition()
        {
            foreach (GeometryBody g in this.ListOfBodies)
            {
                g.Position = new Point(g.Position.X + this.Position.X, g.Position.Y + this.Position.Y,  g.Position.Z + this.Position.Z);
            }
        }

Comment: This is what you said I should do, I think it is right this way?

Comment: No, that would have a big problem, if you do that each time you render each object it will add the position of the group displacing them infinitely, if you do that when you move the group then if you move an object it will lose the group position, you need something a bit more complicated, that's why I suggested to implement the `+` operator, in this wahy when you render you could render at `g.Position + group.Position`

Comment: Thank you. But I have no idea how to implement the + operator?

Comment: This tutorial from MSDN can help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx
Also, an operator overload is a bit of syntatic sugar, you could always use the same code you posted but instead of setting it to the object creating it each time you will render  the object, something like `var tmpPos = new Point(g.Position.X + this.Position.X, g.Position.Y + this.Position.Y, g.Position.Z + this.Position.Z); Render(theObject, Position);` But for me is more clear `Render(theObject, g.Position + group.Position);`

Comment: Thanks you, I have few ideas now. I just don't understand what is render doing? Is it showing objects graphically or? What is this line doing --> Render(theObject, Position)?

Comment: Don't you have a function to represent the objects on screen? That's rendering the object, as I don't know your inner code I assume you have a function named Render to which you pass the object and the position to represent it on screen, that's the render function. If you need more concrete info you need to add a lot more code to the question.

Comment: It's actually something I am practicing for exam. Previous exam was like this and I am practicing it now. Thing is, text is obscure. Professor didn't say much about rendering the object. I assume we don't have to take care about it. I don't know how I should represent the link between the "geometry part" and "rendering part".

Comment: Well, then, for one part your teacher is a moron as depending on how your engine is designed the approach can be extremely diferent, for the other part, you must change your approach, you need on each `GeometryBody` to have a `Parent` property of type `GeometryBody`, replace `Position`  with a property, then when someone access `Position` you check if the object has a Parent, if true you return `this.position + Parent.Position` else you return `this.position`, then, when you add a body to the group you set to that body the group as parent.

Comment: Well, he is a moron. We all have troubles with him and with his retarded assingments. Well, that method actually sounds great. Will try it now! Thanks!